# Are programming languages just a compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

Is this true that programming languages are not anything except some grammar and rules for writing commands, and a compiler can translate them into machine-code?

if yes, then speed of a programming language doesn't make sense, because it's the compilers' job to create optimized machine-code. And this means if we create best compilers for all programming languages they will have all the same performance, is this true?
And on the other hand when we say `c++20` is released this means that a new compiler is published which can understand some new grammar rules added to `c++`, yes?

PS : in this post I don't want to mention interpreted languages.

Comment: When people say that C++20 has been released that means that the new version of the language standard has been released. It says nothing about compilers.

Comment: @sepp2k this means that no software (compiler or anything else) is released? just a documentation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that there are many different C++ compilers and they tend to add support for new language versions at different times. Neither of them defines the language. Like when we say "C++20 adds feature X" that's not a statement about what compilers implement. It's saying that feature X is included in the C++20 standard. That means that a compiler has to support that feature in order to claim (full) support for C++20, but even if no compiler ever implements a feature, the feature would still be a part of C++20 - there just wouldn't be any implementations of C++20.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks! your comment helped me understand , but it looks strange for me, because in the way you said someone who knows little about programming (like me:) ) can create a programming language. As I understand in this case the biggest challenge is creating the compiler, is it true?

Comment: Writing a programming language specification isn't exactly trivial. You'd be surprised how hard it can be to express exactly how a language is supposed to behave in a way that's precise, unambiguous and covers all cases. Certainly a good understanding of programming languages is required to end up with anything sensible (and implementable). But yes, you can write a language specification without writing any software, publish it somewhere and then say that you have designed a language. That's not very useful though¹ unless you have someone that wants to implement it.

Comment: ¹ Well, it can be useful in some cases for educational purposes and/or as a thought experiment. For example you might define a language and then proof that it's actually unimplementable. Or you might define one and then ask students to proof whether it's Turing complete etc. or to implement it. Though languages designed for the latter purpose usually do come with a reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> And this means if we create best compilers for all programming languages they will have all the same performance, is this true?

No. A great optimizing compiler can not make a bad algorithm faster than an unoptimized good algorithm.

> And on the other hand when we say c++20 is released this means that a new compiler is published which can understand some new grammar rules added to c++, yes?

Not necessarily. While almost every new version of a programming language may have some new syntax, there is no universal rule that an update has to have new grammar rules.

I currently program mainly in Prolog which has basically a few basic syntax rules. All of the new versions typically add libraries, patches, fixes, changes, but with Prolog the basic syntax of [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms) has been rock solid since the start.

While many would not consider untyped [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) a programming language, it has only Abstraction and Application; the syntax does not change.

Comment: I think my question isn't so clear, I mean a programming language is anything more than some standards? or it is a software?
if a programming language is just some standard, so anyone can create a compiler or interpreter based on those standards, and this means I can run a simple calculation on python faster than c (with the same algorithm), and this is opposite of the thing that always people say.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi The problem with that is that it's much harder to create a fast Python implementation than a fast C implementation. You're right that speed is a property of the interpreter or compiler, not the language, but some languages are designed with efficient implementations in mind and some or not. Given a comparable amount of implementation effort, implementations of the former will generally outperform implementations of the latter.